# Spacy: How to achieve multi threading speedups with nlp.pipe?

Tags: python, spacy

I have a corpus of ~1M documents each about 50 words long.  I'm running on a machine with 32 virtual cores and significant ram in AWS.

"contents" is a list of each document.  When I try to process "contents" with nlp.pipe, it still takes ~ 20-40mins.  This seems odd to me since I've heard that spacy releases python's GIL, and can process 100k words per second.

Below is my code - am I not setting the pipeline up correctly in order to process faster?

```
nlp = sp.load('en_core_web_lg')

t0_nlp = time()
contents_piped=[]
for doc in nlp.pipe(contents, n_threads=16, batch_size=10000):
    contents_piped.append(doc)
t1_nlp = time()
dur_nlp = t1_nlp-t0_nlp
```